# CORS ORIGIN ISSUE

Tags: php

URL :  http://localhost:8080/v1/integration/dataset as i am hitting to call api its localhost but same have live server to0.

i am heating as POST Request but is convertting it OPTION in place of POST and 
error occurs : OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/v1/integration/dataset 405 (Method Not Allowed)

var data = "{\n\"name\":\"dsdsdsd\"\n  \"task\":\"dhdkjdhkjdshdasj\",\n  '\n}";

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/v1/integration/dataset");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"); 
xhr.send(data);
```

var data = "{\n\"name\":\"dsdsdsd\"\n  \"task\":\"dhdkjdhkjdshdasj\",\n  '\n}";

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/v1/integration/dataset");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.send(data);
```

test.html:26 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/v1/integration/dataset 405 (Method Not Allowed)

(anonymous) @ test.html:26
test.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/integration/dataset' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

Please add these headers here. I am experiencing the same issue and fixed this way:

```php
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

This will allow all the headers to be sent during the preflight `OPTIONS` method.

> **Note:** You may want to whitelist the domains instead of putting `*` for the first one.

Comment: ```i have added this shared code :

 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");``` but still getting same error

Comment: @GajendraBitcot Can you confirm by checking the network tab and clearing the cache? A screenshot of the network tab with the POST data will be great.

Comment: @GajendraBitcot Would you like to have a quick look at [Making Axios Request Payload work with PHP & What goes behind?](https://blog.praveen.science/making-axios-request-payload-work-with-php/)